# (Mac Intel) HP PS driver prints in B&W from Adobe Reader after installing Cannon PS driver

Tags: macos, drivers

I have a unique problem that leaves me at a loss as to where to start troubleshooting. We have three Macs we use for graphics, two of which are PowerPC and one which is Intel. They are set up to print to an HP 5500dn, but occasionally this printer gets tied up with a massive print job, so I installed the PS driver (iR-PSv1.81MacOSX) for the Cannon C3200 Printer/copier on each of the machines. Both of the PowerPC Macs installed without issue, but the Intel Mac exhibits strange behavior:

- I've confirmed that while the Cannon driver is installed (whether or not the Cannon is set up for printing in print settings), the HP 5500dn will print in color from Safari, but only prints in black and white from Adobe Reader.
- The Cannon printer itself has not exhibited any strange behavior
- As soon as the Cannon driver is uninstalled, the HP 5500dn prints in color from Adobe Reader again.

We run a network of Windows PCs, and the 'Mac room' mostly takes care of itself, so we don't have any experienced Mac administrators onsite. The Cannon is capable of Appletalk, but the PS driver seemed easier to work with (and Appletalk is currently disable on the Cannon. I'm not against using the Appletalk compatible drivers, but I would rather use the PS driver if at all possible - I don't want to open up the proverbial can of worms.

If someone has any clues or suggestions that would help troubleshoot this problem, I would be grateful. I've already done some googling, but due to the obscure nature of this problem, I haven't been very successful.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the print system.  On OSX 10.5 and 10.6, open System Preferences / Print & Fax, hold down the Control key and click in any empty spot in the box where the pritners are listed. All queues will be deleted (but this does not affect the driver installs). Reboot & re-add the printers.

If that doesn't help, uninstall/reinstall Adobe.

If still ng, workaround this by printing PDF's from the Mac Preview app.

Comment: I'll be trying your suggestions as soon as I can (in the next couple of weeks). What does resetting the print system do - does it just delete the print queues? Do you have any idea what might be causing Adobe to print in B&W?

Comment: Here's some info on the ink system reset command:
http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1341

Couldn't tell you about Adobe but printing issues with it are common.  Like I mentioned before, uninstall/reinstall & use Preview if you get stuck.

Comment: FYI I haven't forgotten about this Q, I just haven't been able to tackle it yet.